# Tela 'pisca' ao clicar no menu antes de deslizar até o destino

Tags: javascript, jquery

deem uma olhada nesse link [Fun Wake Park](http://www.funwakepark.com.br) cliquem no menu e vão perceber que antes de acontecer o efeito de deslize, a pagina vai ate o destino e volta rapidão dando uma piscada, o que pode ser isso ? Estou usando o `jquery.easing`, mandaram eu usar o `ScrollTo` do `Tweenmax` mas achei complicado não entendi como se aplica.

Podem me ajudar com essa ?

Código que chama o plugin:

```
$(function() {
$('a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);

  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top}, 2000,'easeInOutExpo');

 });
```

});

Comment: O JS na página está todo minificado... dificil ajudar. Parece-me um FOUC mas a ágina não está a carregar... testa `event.preventDefault()` para evitar que o browser faça scroll e no milisegundo depois vem o animate do jQuery.

Comment: Através do que vc flw fui pesquisar, e testei adicionar um return false; na função e aparentemente testando no local deu certo.  Obrigado

Comment: E testaste com `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Testei sim, não sei se fiz errado mas acabou n dando certo, somente o return deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penso que o problema é não estares a parar o evento.

Quando clicas numa âncora o browser vai abrir numa página nova, ou saltar para o ponto da página. Se usares uma url ele vai para uma nova página, se usares `#id` ele vai para uma certa posição onde encontra esse elemento dentro da mesma página.

Uma vez que esse comportamento não é parado, o browser vai para esse sitio da página e ao mesmo tempo começa um scroll. Isso baralha e dá esse efeito.

Se a minha teoria estiver certa (pois não consigo testar no teu site) precisar parar o evento. E isso podes fazer assim:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').bind('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // ou return false no final desta função
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top}, 2000,'easeInOutExpo');
    });
});
```

Comment: Foi exatamente o que fiz seguindo sua linha de raciocínio fui pesquisar, e testei o `return:false;` e deu certo, ja sub o projeto pro ar de uma olhada.  muito obrigado